# Prevent reRendering of whole Visualforce Page when changing between <apex:tab>

Tags: visualforce, tab

in my Visualforce page I have created an apex:pageblock that consists of an apex:selectList for sorting and an apex:tabPanel (Leads & Accounts)

[image]

Now when I switch between these tabs the entire visualforce page reloads which includes a google map. This not what I want and at the same time can't figure out why this is happening. What 'action' tells the page to reRender when switching tabs?

I only want the pageblock to reRender. This behaviour is fine when I change the value of the 'selectList' element in order to sort the records inside the tabs.

Here is the code that handles the pageblock:

```
<apex:pageblock id="sort">
        <apex:form >
            sortieren nach:   <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
                                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="sort" action="{!findNearbyPotentials}"></apex:actionSupport>
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Distance" itemLabel="Entfernung"/>
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Jobads" itemLabel="Anzahl Anzeigen"/>
                              </apex:selectList>
         </apex:form>


    <apex:tabPanel >
     <!-- TAB LEADS -->
      <apex:tab label="Leads ({!warehouses.size})" disabled="{!IF(warehouses.size = 0,true,false)}" >
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container-fluid">
         <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto !important;">     
          <apex:repeat value="{!warehouses}" var="war">

             <style type="text/css">
               .col1 {width:5px; text-align:left;}
               .col2 {width:400px; text-align:left;}
             </style>

              <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="col1, col2" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#e2ecf1'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor =''">
                <apex:image url="{!IF(war.Nicht_zugewiesene_Leadevents_Counter__c > 0,URLFOR($Resource.mitle),IF(war.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c = currentAccount.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c && war.Mitarbeiternzahl_final__c = currentAccount.Mitarbeiternzahl_final__c,URLFOR($Resource.perfect_fit), 
                      URLFOR($Resource.ms_marker)))}" styleClass="imageStyle" id="MyImage" onmouseover="ImageOver(this)" onmouseout="ImageNormal(this)"/> 
                  <apex:panelGroup >

                                <!-- Hover for Detail -->   
                                <a id="{!war.Id}"
                                onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!war.Id}', '/{!war.Id}/m?retURL={!war.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
                                onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!war.Id}').hide();"
                                onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!war.Id}', '/{!war.Id}/m?retURL={!war.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
                                onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!war.Id}').hide();"
                                href="/{!war.Id}" target="_blank"> 
                                {!war.company}
                                 </a> <br/>

                                <!-- Jump to location and highlight -->
                                <apex:form > 
                                 <apex:commandLink action="{!findNearbyPotentials}" value="{!war.Street}, {!war.PostalCode} {!war.City}" reRender="map">  
                                     <apex:param name="HoverLead" value="{!war.id}" assignTo="{!HoverLead}" /> 
                                      <apex:param name="center" value="{!war.MapCurrentAddress__c}" assignTo="{!mapCenter}" />
                                      <apex:param name="zoom" value="13" assignTo="{!zoom}"/>
                                      <apex:param name="HoverAccount" value="" assignTo="{!HoverAccount}" /> 
                                 </apex:commandLink>  
                                </apex:form>  

                                 <!-- Distanz -->
                                 <apex:variable var="url" value="GoogleDistance | https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=+{!currentAccount.Geolocation__c}&daddr=+{!war.Geolocation__c}" />
                                 <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(NOT(CONTAINS(selectedField,'Jobads')), true, false)}" value="{!MID(url, FIND('|', url) + 1, LEN(url))}" target="_blank">{!distances[war.id]}</apex:outputLink>  

                                 <!-- Anzahl Anzeigen -->             
                                 <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(selectedField,'Jobads'), true, false)}" value="{!war.indexurl__c}" target="_blank">{!war.AD_MS_Rel_Anzahl_bez__c} Anzeigen</apex:outputLink>                     

                                 <!-- Branche -->     
                                 <br/>          
                                 <apex:outputText value="{!war.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c}"></apex:outputText>                         

                     </apex:panelGroup>                                                  
                    </apex:panelGrid> 
                   </apex:repeat> 
                  </div>                 
                 </apex:outputpanel> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
               </apex:tab>


    <!-- TAB ACCOUNTS -->
       <apex:tab label="Accounts ({!pot.size})" disabled="{!IF(pot.size = 0,true,false)}" >  
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container-fluid">
          <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto !important;">     
           <apex:repeat value="{!pot}" var="pote">

                <style type="text/css">
                     .col1 {width:5px; text-align:left;}
                     .col2 {width:400px; text-align:left;}
                </style>

                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="col1, col2" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#e2ecf1'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor =''">
                      <apex:image url="{!IF(pote.Nicht_zugewiesene_Leadevents_Counter__c > 0,URLFOR($Resource.mitle),IF(pote.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c = currentAccount.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c && pote.Mitarbeiternzahl_final__c = currentAccount.Mitarbeiternzahl_final__c,URLFOR($Resource.perfect_fit), 
                      URLFOR($Resource.ms_marker)))}" styleClass="imageStyle" id="MyImage" onmouseover="ImageOver(this)" onmouseout="ImageNormal(this)"/> 
                        <apex:panelGroup >

                               <!-- Hover for Detail -->   
                                <a id="{!pote.Id}"
                                onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!pote.Id}', '/{!pote.Id}/m?retURL={!pote.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
                                onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!pote.Id}').hide();"
                                onfocus="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!pote.Id}', '/{!pote.Id}/m?retURL={!pote.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
                                onblur="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!pote.Id}').hide();"
                                href="/{!pote.Id}" target="_blank"> 
                                {!pote.Name}
                                </a> 
                                <br/>

                                <!-- Jump to location and highlight -->
                                 <apex:form >  
                                    <apex:commandLink action="{!findNearbyPotentials}" value="{!pote.ShippingStreet}, {!pote.ShippingPostalCode} {!pote.ShippingCity}" reRender="map">  
                                    <apex:param name="HoverAccount" value="{!pote.id}" assignTo="{!HoverAccount}" />
                                    <apex:param name="center" value="{!pote.MapCurrentAddress__c}" assignTo="{!mapCenter}" />
                                    <apex:param name="zoom" value="13" assignTo="{!zoom}"/>
                                    <apex:param name="HoverLead" value="" assignTo="{!HoverLead}" /> 
                                  </apex:commandLink>  
                                 </apex:form>   

                                <!-- Distanz -->
                                <apex:variable var="url" value="GoogleDistance | https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=+{!currentAccount.Geolocation__c}&daddr=+{!pote.Geolocation__c}" />
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(NOT(CONTAINS(selectedField,'Jobads')), true, false)}" value="{!MID(url, FIND('|', url) + 1, LEN(url))}" target="_blank">{!distances[pote.id]}</apex:outputLink>  

                                <!-- Anzahl Anzeigen -->             
                                <apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(selectedField,'Jobads'), true, false)}" value="{!pote.indexurl__c}" target="_blank">{!pote.AD_MS_Rel_Anzahl_bez__c} Anzeigen</apex:outputLink> 

                                 <!-- Branche -->   
                                 <br/>           
                                 <apex:outputText value="{!pote.WirtschaftszweigWZ08__c}"></apex:outputText>                     

                        </apex:panelGroup>                                               
                       </apex:panelGrid> 
                      </apex:repeat> 
                     </div> 
                    </apex:outputpanel>                             
                   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
                  </apex:tab>     
                 </apex:tabPanel>      

     </apex:pageblock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm)

#### apex:tabPanel > Attributes

> ...
>
> switchType · String · The implementation method for switching between tabs. Possible values include "client", "server", and "ajax". If not specified, this value defaults to "server".

As you don't specify anything, it is set to `server`, which means that it is salesforce the one re-rendering everythings going back and forth. If you use `client`, the whole switch would be in Javascript and the information would be kept (tabs are loaded and just hidden using css and by doing so, keeping all information you have inside.)

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client">
...
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Note: 
    You sould be careful if you have required inputs / validations spread around the different tabs.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. This behaviour was exactly what I was looking for!